# Unrecognized VM option 'PrintGCDateStamps'

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have a problem with setting up Kafka environment.

```
$ bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
[0.005s][warning][gc] -Xloggc is deprecated. Will use -Xlog:gc:C:/Users/Szymon/kafka_2.13-3.6.1/logs/zookeeper-gc.log instead.
Unrecognized VM option 'PrintGCDateStamps'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I tried to change kafka-run-class.sh

```
# GC options
GC_FILE_SUFFIX='-gc.log'
GC_LOG_FILE_NAME=''
if [ "x$GC_LOG_ENABLED" = "xtrue" ]; then
  GC_LOG_FILE_NAME=$DAEMON_NAME$GC_FILE_SUFFIX
  JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION=$($JAVA -version 2>&1 | sed -E -n 's/.* version "([^.-])."/\1/p')
  if [[ "$JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION" -ge "9" ]] ; then
    KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS="-Xlog:gc*:file=$LOG_DIR/$GC_LOG_FILE_NAME:time,tags:filecount=10,filesize=100M"
  else
    KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS="-Xloggc:$LOG_DIR/$GC_LOG_FILE_NAME -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=100M"
  fi
fi
```

But nothing works. Does somebody know what to do?

Comment: It's possible to run kafka without zookeeper since kafka 3.3.1. This is known as kraft mode and greatly simplifies the deployment of kafka clusters. See [KIP-500](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-500%3A+Replace+ZooKeeper+with+a+Self-Managed+Metadata+Quorum) and [kraft](https://developer.confluent.io/learn/kraft/)

Comment: Unclear what Java version you're using, but try again with 17